# Why do Python "".split() and "".split(",") produce a different result?

Tags: python, string, split

This is the result when I apply split() against an empty string with default delimiter and with a "," as delimiter in Python.

```
>>> print "".split(',')
['']
>>> print "".split()
[]
```

Can somebody please explain why we should expect this behavior?

Comment: Documentation should be the 'first reference'. Someone wrote it - honor their time/effort.

Comment: I asked because I couldn't find in the docs. If this bother you, don't answer. There is no point to make a comment like this without providing any references.

Comment: Improve searching methods then. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html was found for "python str.split" then Ctrl+F "split" and read. Almost a LMGTFY. There are some things that are harder to find; but not the Python string API documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior is as documented (emphasis added):

> split(...)
>   S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
>   delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>       splits are done. **If sep is not specified or is None, any
>       whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
>       from the result.**

Empty strings are removed only if you do *not* specify a separator.

#### Using `help` From Python's Interactive Prompt

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = ""
>>> s.split()
[]
>>> help(s.split)
```

This provides the information quoted above.

Comment: Thank you. It just seems odd to me. I have just several days into Python and this takes me hours to figure out.

Comment: @trananhtuan Have you tried Python's interactive help system?  See the addition to the answer.

Comment: @John1024 No I haven't. Thanks for the help with interactive help system, I get it now.